# SBT Assembly - Deduplicate error & Exclude error

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am trying to build a JAR with dependencies using sbt-assembly. But I am running into this error again and again. I have tried multiple different things but I end up here. I am pretty new to SBT and wanted to get some help on this one. Here are the build.sbt & assembly.sbt files.

**build.sbt**

```
seq(assemblySettings: _*)

name := "StreamTest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10" % "1.1.0"
```

**project/assembly.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
```

When I run the sbt assembly command, I am getting this error below.

```
[info] Including: joda-time-2.5.jar
[info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[info] Merging files...
[warn] Merging 'about_files/LICENSE.txt' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'about_files/NOTICE.txt' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/NOTICE' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'org/xerial/snappy/native/README' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/maven/org.xerial.snappy/snappy-java/LICENSE' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/license' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'about.html' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/README.txt' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'LICENSE.txt' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/LICENSE' with strategy 'rename'
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' with strategy 'discard'
java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.transaction/orbits/javax.transaction-1.1.1.v201105210645.jar:META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA
/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.servlet/orbits/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA
/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.mail.glassfish/orbits/javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar:META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA
/Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.activation/orbits/javax.activation-1.1.0.v201105071233.jar:META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA
    at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.sbtassembly$Plugin$Assembly$$applyStrategy$1(Plugin.scala:253)
    at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$$anonfun$15.apply(Plugin.scala:270)
    at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$$anonfun$15.apply(Plugin.scala:267)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.applyStrategies(Plugin.scala:272)
    at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.x$4$lzycompute$1(Plugin.scala:172)
    at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.x$4$1(Plugin.scala:170)
    at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.stratMapping$lzycompute$1(Plugin.scala:170)
    at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.stratMapping$1(Plugin.scala:170)
    at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.inputs$lzycompute$1(Plugin.scala:214)
    at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.inputs$1(Plugin.scala:204)
    at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$.apply(Plugin.scala:230)
    at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$$anonfun$assemblyTask$1.apply(Plugin.scala:373)
    at sbtassembly.Plugin$Assembly$$anonfun$assemblyTask$1.apply(Plugin.scala:370)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.transaction/orbits/javax.transaction-1.1.1.v201105210645.jar:META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA
[error] /Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.servlet/orbits/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar:META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA
[error] /Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.mail.glassfish/orbits/javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar:META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA
[error] /Users/user/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.activation/orbits/javax.activation-1.1.0.v201105071233.jar:META-INF/ECLIPSEF.RSA
[error] Total time: 23 s, completed Nov 28, 2014 9:32:53 PM
```

**sbt-version**

```
0.13.6
```

**EDIT**

Now after looking around I have made another change to exclude any dependencies, as part of another question on stackoverflow.

**Updated build.sbt**

```
seq(assemblySettings: _*)

name := "StreamTest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10" % "1.1.0"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.servlet").
    exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.transaction").
    exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.mail").
    exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.activation").
    exclude("commons-beanutils", "commons-beanutils-core").
    exclude("commons-collections", "commons-collections").
    exclude("commons-collections", "commons-collections").
    exclude("com.esotericsoftware.minlog", "minlog")
)
```

When I run the assembly command again, this is the error that I get.

```
build.sbt:14: error: not found: value exclude
    exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.servlet").
    ^
```

EDIT 2:

Updated build.sbt

```
import AssemblyKeys._

seq(assemblySettings: _*)

name := "SparkStreamingKinesis"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.10" % "1.1.0"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".RSA" => MergeStrategy.first
    case x =>
       val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
       oldStrategy(x)
}
```

After making the update, here is the error that I am getting. I tried to do an import of assemblyMergeStrategy, but it doesn't look like a class that I can import.

```
build.sbt:21: error: not found: value assemblyMergeStrategy
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
^
[error] Type error in expression
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one to exclude only `ECLIPSEF.RSA` file, because excluding whole dependencies, which your libraries may need, is a bad idea :)

[Deduplication error in build.sbt when building a fat jar using sbt assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925233/deduplication-error-in-build-sbt-when-building-a-fat-jar-using-sbt-assembly/25925675#25925675)

Solution for latest `0.12.0` version of assembly plugin:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".RSA" => MergeStrategy.first 
    case x =>
       val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
       oldStrategy(x)
}
```

project/assembly.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")
```

See https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#merge-strategy

P.S. About `exclude`: you can't just specify `exclude` in libraryDependencies - you need something like this: `"log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.15" exclude("javax.jms", "jms")`. See [Library Management](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Management.html)

Comment: thank you for the quick reply dk14. When I added the assemblyMergeStrategy, I ran into another error. I have updated the question.

Comment: just add `import AssemblyKeys._`

Comment: hey dk14, I added it to the build.sbt file but I still get the same error.

Comment: Move to the latest version of plugin: 0.12.0 + sbt 0.13.6+. If you have older version of sbt - check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25925233/deduplication-error-in-build-sbt-when-building-a-fat-jar-using-sbt-assembly/25925675#25925675

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had two dependencies that had dependencies to the same assemblies, but different versions. I simply had to match up the assemblies.