# SBT package subproject in subproject

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using sbt 0.13.12, and this is my project

`root
 |--- common
 |--- sub1
 |--- sub2`

In `build.sbt` file I set `sub1` depends on `common`. It's OK if I run by `sbt project sub1 run`. But, when I package subprojects as jar files, I run the sub1.jar file, the error shown that `sub1` could not find a class of `common`.

*My purpose is packaging `sub1.jar` and `sub2.jar` with `common` codes are compiled in each jar files.*

**-- UPDATE --**
I tried as suggestions in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129021/sbt-package-subproject-in-subproject/40130416#40130416). It got this issue when run `sbt assembly`:

`[error] (utils/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\javax.inject\javax.inject\jars\javax.inject-1.jar:javax/inject/Inject.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.glassfish.hk2.external\javax.inject\jars\javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar:javax/inject/Inject.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\javax.inject\javax.inject\jars\javax.inject-1.jar:javax/inject/Named.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.glassfish.hk2.external\javax.inject\jars\javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar:javax/inject/Named.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\javax.inject\javax.inject\jars\javax.inject-1.jar:javax/inject/Provider.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.glassfish.hk2.external\javax.inject\jars\javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar:javax/inject/Provider.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\javax.inject\javax.inject\jars\javax.inject-1.jar:javax/inject/Qualifier.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.glassfish.hk2.external\javax.inject\jars\javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar:javax/inject/Qualifier.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\javax.inject\javax.inject\jars\javax.inject-1.jar:javax/inject/Scope.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.glassfish.hk2.external\javax.inject\jars\javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar:javax/inject/Scope.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\javax.inject\javax.inject\jars\javax.inject-1.jar:javax/inject/Singleton.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.glassfish.hk2.external\javax.inject\jars\javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar:javax/inject/Singleton.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\aopalliance\aopalliance\jars\aopalliance-1.0.jar:org/aopalliance/aop/Advice.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.glassfish.hk2.external\aopalliance-repackaged\jars\aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar:org/aopalliance/aop/Advice.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\aopalliance\aopalliance\jars\aopalliance-1.0.jar:org/aopalliance/aop/AspectException.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.glassfish.hk2.external\aopalliance-repackaged\jars\aopalliance-repackaged-2.4.0-b34.jar:org/aopalliance/aop/AspectException.class
....
(truncated because it's too long)
....
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.hadoop\hadoop-yarn-common\jars\hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/factories/package-info.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.hadoop\hadoop-yarn-api\jars\hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/factories/package-info.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.hadoop\hadoop-yarn-common\jars\hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/factory/providers/package-info.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.hadoop\hadoop-yarn-api\jars\hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/factory/providers/package-info.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.hadoop\hadoop-yarn-common\jars\hadoop-yarn-common-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/util/package-info.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.hadoop\hadoop-yarn-api\jars\hadoop-yarn-api-2.2.0.jar:org/apache/hadoop/yarn/util/package-info.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.spark\spark-core_2.11\jars\spark-core_2.11-2.0.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.spark\spark-launcher_2.11\jars\spark-launcher_2.11-2.0.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.spark\spark-tags_2.11\jars\spark-tags_2.11-2.0.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.spark-project.spark\unused\jars\unused-1.0.0.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.spark\spark-network-common_2.11\jars\spark-network-common_2.11-2.0.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.spark\spark-network-shuffle_2.11\jars\spark-network-shuffle_2.11-2.0.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.spark\spark-unsafe_2.11\jars\spark-unsafe_2.11-2.0.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.spark\spark-sql_2.11\jars\spark-sql_2.11-2.0.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.spark\spark-sketch_2.11\jars\spark-sketch_2.11-2.0.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] C:\Users\WindowsUser\.ivy2\cache\org.apache.spark\spark-catalyst_2.11\jars\spark-catalyst_2.11-2.0.1.jar:org/apache/spark/unused/UnusedStubClass.class
[error] Total time: 670 s, completed Oct 20, 2016 10:36:31 AM`

And, Yes! I searched and followed these solutions, but cannot resolve the new issue:

- [sbt-assembly: deduplication found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144484/sbt-assembly-deduplication-found-error)
- [spark + sbt-assembly: "deduplicate: different file contents found in the following"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446984/spark-sbt-assembly-deduplicate-different-file-contents-found-in-the-followi)
- [SBT Assembly - Deduplicate error & Exclude error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198216/sbt-assembly-deduplicate-error-exclude-error)

Comment: use sbt-assembly plugin to create a fat jar with all depedencies. Or use the standard approach of supplying the dependency jars in classpath.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, for the supplying the dependency jars approach, I can make it, but I would like to build a jar file which contains the common module.

Comment: that is happening because you have dependencies that depend on different versions of same library. If you want to use sbt-assembly you will have to choose a merge strategy but that will most probably cause some incompatibility errors. So just stay with the class path approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using this plugin https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly you can create fat jars, that contains all your dependencies.

In this case, you can type:

```
sbt
project sub1
assembly
```

**EDIT**

Regarding the deduplicate error, you have to use a merge strategy for your dependencies.
I have been using the following approach that solved 99% of my problems:

```
lazy val mergeStrategy = Seq(
  assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
    case PathList("META-INF", "io.netty.versions.properties") => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList(ps@_*) if ps.last endsWith ".html" => MergeStrategy.first
    case "application.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
    case "reference.conf" => MergeStrategy.concat
    case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf") => MergeStrategy.discard
    case m if m.toLowerCase.matches("meta-inf.*\\.sf$") => MergeStrategy.discard
    case _ => MergeStrategy.first
  }
)

lazy val root = Project(
  id = "root",
  base = file(".")
) aggregate(common, database, server)

lazy val server = (project in file("server"))
  .settings(cdbServerConfig: _*)
  .settings(mergeStrategy: _*)
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= (commonDependencies ++ akkaDependencies ++ jsonDependencies))
  .dependsOn(database)

lazy val database = (project in file("database"))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= (commonDependencies ++ databaseDependencies))
  .dependsOn(common)

lazy val common = (project in file("common"))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies)
```

So in my case, I want to package the server project, that depends on the database project which depends on the common project.

Using that merge strategy works fine to me.

But as I said, in 99% it works, but when it does not, I have been using the following plugin:

https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph

So I can see the dependency tree and see what is conflicting.

Comment: Hi @ThiagoPereira, I have just updated my question. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: @GiaDuongDucMinh I have updated my answer, that a look on that.